# Double value comparison with constants

Tags: java

There is `double signum(double d)` function in Math package which returns zero if the argument is zero, 1.0 if the argument is greater than zero, -1.0 if the argument is less than zero.

Is it safe to compare result value with `==` or should I use something else?

For example:

```
if(Math.signum(someDouble) == 1.0) {
    do something
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason why you think it may not be safe?

Comment: I have read that doubles should not be compared with just ==, but in this case I compare result value returned by the function which has constants for representing result values.

Comment: It's as safe as it is to assume that the `==` comparison inside `signum` is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is "safe" according to the specification of this function provided in the documentation. However, if you just need to test the signum, why don't you just do `someDouble > 0` ?. Math.signum has no use here, it is useful for some formulas but there it is not necessary.